# can qualified namespace be same as default namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, schema

Can a qualified namespace be the same as the default namespace?

Can someone point me to the specific point in the w3 specs that allow or deny this - I have tried reading through http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/ but cannot find the relevant info.

So is the following valid?

```
<root xmlns="http://abc">
   <address xmlns:ns1="http://abc">
       <!-- using qualified namespace which resolves to same value as default name space -->
       <ns1:addressLine1>my address</ns1:addressLine1> 
   </address>
   <!-- this next address element is from the same schema as the above -->
   <address>
       <addressLine1>my address</addressLine1> 
   </address>
</root>
```

Comment: The answer is yes.  I doubt the spec goes into this edge case.

Comment: Richard - I think that too. Why do you think it is valid?

Comment: A default namespace is just that.  A child element can override the default namespace with any namespace it cares to use.  This is no mention in the spec that the override namespace can not be the default namepsace.